# How to run nodemon + forever in the background

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon, forever

Good morning!

I need my node.js server running in the background. I just saw this answer: [Forever + Nodemon running together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369018/forever-nodemon-running-together)

I understand the idea, and I think that it's great, but when I use

```
forever -c "nodemon --exitcrash" app.js
```

the nodemon console stills visible. How can I hide the console?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: try running them as bacground process

Comment: The question is how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using pm2 [pm2 guides](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

With pm2 your application runs in the background and:-

- Can auto-start on server reboots
- You can even set pm2 to watch for file changes and reload your application
- You can monitor your application and see resource utilization
- You can view logs
- You can run your application in cluster and load-balance requests using pm2